# MS Access Connection works in local but not working in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

As a MVC developer I am creating an application for a school, I have a MS Access db and it is located inside my application, in the `app_data` folder. I created the connection string in the `web.config` file like below

```
<add name="WMOERP1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='|DataDirectory|\Register.mdb'" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

It works perfectly in my local system but when I uploaded it in production I got the error

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Please help me how can I solve this
I also tried to change the connection string below you can see that but still having the issue

```
<add name="WMOERP1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='|DataDirectory|\Register.mdb'" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

Please help me .

Comment: Why do you use the ACE.12 in production while in your PC you use the JET.4.0?

Comment: I used jet.4.0 in production but i got the error above having

Comment: Compile your app for x86 (or AnyCPU with Prefer 32 bit), keep the same connection string (with JET.4.0) and set the production IIS server to allow 32bit applications

Answer (score 0):

An application that uses the Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0 is an application that runs in 32bit mode. Thus you have set your project properties to target the x86 CPU platform or you have set the AnyCPU target platform with the Prefer 32bit flag.

In any case, when you deploy your application on IIS server 64 bit you should inform IIS that you want to run a 32bit application.

This is done going to the IIS configurator, choose Application Pools, create or highlight the application pool where you app will run and, on the right click menu, choose the Advanced Settings menu. From there set the Enable 32 bit application flag to true. Restart everything.

[Here a description of the process](https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a1114/how-to-enable-a-32-bit-application-pool-in-iis-7-dedicated-vps.aspx) with a step by step images

Of course you could keep your original Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 connection string because this library is deployed with the NET Framework libraries and you don't need to do anything.
Instead to change to ACE.12.0 you need to install the libraries and, being your application a 32bit one, you need to install the 32bit version of ACE. The error seems to indicate that you have installed the 64bit version and thus there is no ACE.12.0 for 32bit apps (And no, you can't install both ACEs on the same machine)